Connect device over network using ADB is not working
I'm trying to connect my device to Android studio over the network using adb connect IP address command but it's not working I get this error message :
C:\Users\PC>adb connect 192.168.1.31
cannot connect to 192.168.1.31:5555: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)

My laptop works fine, the issue is only related to my desktop PC
Any solution for this issue? Thank you.

Are the phone and the PC in the same network?

@Robert yes they're both connected the same network

If you are using API level >= 30 on your device, enable wifi debugging and
if you want to do it from command line instead of Android Studio, follow these steps:

Enable developer options on your device
Enable Wireless debugging on your device
On your workstation, open a terminal window and navigate to android_sdk/platform-tools
Find your IP address, port number, and pairing code by selecting Pair device with pairing code
Take note of the IP address, port number, and pairing code displayed on the device
1.On your workstation's terminal, run adb pair ipaddr:port

You can find other options and more details at https://developer.android.com/tools/adb.

Thank you for taking the time to write this answer, but unfortunately, I already did all of this. As I mentioned before, the issue is 100% related to my desktop PC, because on my laptop, the ADB connection works fine.
